# Update app with preloaded SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

My app uses a preloaded and copied from /assets to data/data ( [Ship an application with a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database)) db which is simply a single table of product data and is 'read only' as users do not save to the DB. If I add more products to the DB table I need to get this to existing users. If I update my app with the new DB will the update process delete the old DB that was copied from the assets dir to data/data thereby allowing the 'DBexists' check to fail on first running the updated version thus triggering copying of the new DB from /assets to data/data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, yes, if you put the following snippet it the `onUpgrade()` method:

```
try {
    copyDataBase("database.db");
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.w(TAG, e);
}
```

It may be worth deleting the db file in `copyDataBase()` before writing over it, just to make it less likely to corrupt.

NB: this uses the implementation as used in the accepted answer of the question you linked.

Comment: Having now re-read the upgrade part of the linked question there is every chance that I would mess that up. My DB is only ever likely to be a max of 200k so I will copy it every time the app is run. Will this do the delete in data/data?   File dir = getFilesDir();
File file = new File(dir, "database.db");
boolean deleted = file.delete();

Comment: Yup, I think so, but be careful to catch the error (`FileNotFoundException`) in the case the db doesn't exist. I've found with my db that it is really easy for it to get corrupted/not copy properly, so also be careful and check for that.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head the only thing I can think of is to slightly abuse the onUpgrade() method in your `SQLiteOpenHelper` implementation, and change the database by making a call to this with a new version number and having it do whatever you need it to do in that method.

Saying that, I don't really know much about the Android app update process, so this could be way off.